# Visual basic login form query (Close program after 3 attempts)

Tags: vb.net, forms, authentication

I am trying to create a login form, I have predefined the password.

However, I want to only allow the user 3 attempts at logging in, if they fail it will say, you have used your three attempts and the program will close, here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Dim Password As String
    Dim x As String
    Dim Attempts As Integer
    'maybe use for loop
    Password = "House"
    x = txtPassInput.Text

    If Attempts = 3 Then
        Me.Close()
    End If

    If x = Password Then
        MsgBox("Correct password, you are now logged in.")

    Else
        Attempts = Attempts + 1
        MsgBox("You have entered the wrong password.")

    End If

End Sub
```

What I am asking is, how do I get it to close after 3 attempts, my program doesn't do this yet.

Comment: Don't declare `Attempts` locally in the procedure, declare it in the form.  Otherwise, the variable only exists when the routine is run, meaning it will only ever be 0 when the routine starts, and 1 if an attempt fails.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help! I'm new to visual basic as we have had to change programming languages for year 11 GCSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim LoginAttempts As Integer
Dim currentPassword As String = "House"

Private Sub Login(ByVal passwordFromTextBox As String)
    If Not TestLoginForCompare(passwordFromTextBox) Then
        LoginAttempts += 1
        If LoginAttempts = 3 Then
            'close form/program, return error, lock account
        else
             'notify user of failed attempt 
        End If
    Else
        LoginAttempts = 0
        'proceed to success login
    End If
End Sub
Private Function TestLoginForCompare(ByVal password As String) As Boolean
    If String.Compare(currentPassword, password) Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Actually, the string.compare could be implemented within the Login method without breaking SOLID principles. I split them up on preference but this isn't necessarily necessary.